# "401 Unauthorized" while rendering an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, http-status-code-401

I'm getting "401 Unauthorized" when I try to render or download images in a browser in product cards which is templated by EJS. I guess I should send an access token with GET request when I try to access the image to pass authorization but I don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance!

```
<body>
<% productsCollection.forEach(item => { name = item.name, price = item.salePrices[0].value / 100 + " AZN", itemID = item.id, image = item.customImageLink %>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="<%= image %>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><%= name %></h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><%= price %></a>
        </div>
      </div>
 <% }) %>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you not storing your images in folder which is added as public folder in app.js ?

Comment: I'm not storing images in local folders at all. I take the image URL from the object of each product. That means images are stored on a remote server which declines access when I try to render them.

Comment: That strongly depends on the authorization scheme on your server. You cannot add authorization headers for statically linked resources like `<img src=...`. You *could* (that doesn't mean you *should*, because it has security implications) add a token in a query parameter. If you really need to protect your images, you could also load them via ajax and then add them to the DOM. Or you could just put them in a folder which doesn't need authentication.

Comment: I know it can seem like a too-simple question, but how can I add an authorization header to URL or IMG tag. I know how to do it with Axios or other request tools, but this is the first time I have encountered this type of problem

Comment: @Jeyhun085 It's *not possible* to add an authorization header to an `<img>` tag.

Comment: @derpirscher Okay, then how can the browser pass authorization when it tries to render an image by URL?

Comment: @Jeyhun085 Need to understand more of your asset storage server. Where are you storing those images ?

Comment: @Vipulw You can check directly the URL [link](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/download/5ca9b458-31f0-45ee-a471-50642e9c2ca4)

Comment: This links seems to be pointing to a secured CRM system and yes you need to send a authorization to it. And only possible if you know more information of that CRM

Comment: Refer this link from documentation https://dev.moysklad.ru/doc/api/remap/1.2/#mojsklad-json-api